# Python: Best way to frame a loop with 2 alternating tasks

Tags: python

I have a list of items that I need to process. Easy enough: just a simple `for x in list`.

However, the commands inside the for loop need to be slightly different, on an alternating basis. So 
`n = 0` is handled one way, then `n = 1` a different way; then `n = 2` the same as `n = 0`. Note that `n` and `x` are different!

At the moment, the only way I can think of doing this is with an incremental counter and if statements. I'm presuming there's an easier way?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Put your code in the question.

Comment: look at the in built `enumerate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [modulo](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to alternate:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for idx, ch in enumerate(li):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        # do A
    else:
        # do B
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out enumeration:

```
for n, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        # do things for even-indexed items
    else:
        # do things for odd-indexed items
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle using map and a apply function, each function must be in the same position as the value it needs to operate with.
functional approach

Example:

```
>>> import operator
import functools
import itertools
def apply(f, e):
    return f(e)
elems = range(10)
functs = itertools.cycle([functools.partial(operator.add, 1), functools.partial(operator.add, 2)])
results = list(itertools.starmap(apply, zip(functs, elems)))
print results

[1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11]
```

`apply` method just takes a function and a value, returns the result of applying that function to that value. 
the you `starmap` apply to the list of functions zipped to the list of elements or values, is like zipping 2 lists but one of them contains functions that will consume the other lists values.

Answer (score 1):

python comprehensions can be useful for things like this in a very simple way where in another language you have to write functions and control statements in python you can just do:

```
new_list = [f2(list_item) for i, list_item in zip(range(len(old_list)), old_list) if i%2==0 else f1(list_item)]
```

Comment: this is just wrong, try this one, `new_list = [f2(list_item) if i%2==0 else f1(list_item) for i, list_item in enumerate(oldlist)]`